# Authenticating to Azure AD non-interactively

Tags: asp.net, azure-active-directory

I have an asp.net application where I am trying to integrate AD authentication with out redirecting the user to https://login.microsoftonline.com. I used the following code and did some modification as per the latest documentation but I am getting an error as follows

```
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalException: 'unknown_user_type: Unknown User Type'
```

Here is the code I have written

```
var tenant = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Tenant"];
var serviceUri = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/4061611f-98d4-4484-944c-3796d4c9746f/oauth2/authorize";
var clientID = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientId"];
var userName = "";
var password = "";
var authority = string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Authority"], tenant);
var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
 var credentials = new UserPasswordCredential(userName, password);
 var authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(serviceUri, clientID, credentials);
```

Settings are as follows for tenant and application id

[image]

[image]

Am I missing some thing can some one help me.

Comment: What kind of user are you trying to use? Is it a personal Microsoft account / Azure AD account / Guest Azure AD account / on-prem AD account?

Comment: I am using my own Microsoft account where I have created couple of users in AD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about why the error says "unknown user type", but I'm pretty sure this doesn't work because you are trying to use ROPC flow with a personal Microsoft account.

Resource Owner Password Credentials (ROPC) flow does not work if:

- The user is a personal Microsoft account
- The user has MFA enabled
- The user's password has expired

It also doesn't work with Guest accounts if I recall correctly.

In general I recommend avoiding this method of authentication and instead redirect the user to the Azure AD login page.
Being unable to use multi-factor authentication is usually a pretty big reason to avoid this flow.

Also I'm pretty sure your `serviceUri` is wrong.
The parameter should define the API you want the tokens for, not a URL to the Azure AD authorization page.

Comment: Hi juunas yeah the code worked when I redirect it to Azure AD login page, I am getting the required tokens too. But instead of redirecting to ad login page I am trying to achieve it by passing the username and password

Comment: What's the reason for not using the Azure AD login page?

Comment: No specific reason just trying it out so that an extra redirection is required

Comment: Okay, but the approach won't work for your personal Microsoft account + the other cases I mentioned.